# How to keep generator function yielding values after throwing an error?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

In Dart language, how can I create an error in a generator function while keeping it creating values?

```
import 'dart:math' show Random;

main() {
  sum20RandomNumbers().then((sum) {
    print("Sum: $sum");
  });
}

Future<double> sum20RandomNumbers() async {
  var randomStream = generateRandomNumbers().handleError((error) {
    print('Ignore large number: ${error}');
    // How can I ignore error here?
  });

  int count = 0;
  double sum = 0;
  await for (var n in randomStream) {
    print(n);
    sum += n;
    if (++count >= 20) // sum 20 numbers at most
      break;
  }
  return sum;
}

Stream<double> generateRandomNumbers([int seed]) async* {
  final random = Random(seed);
  while (true) {
    final nextDouble = random.nextDouble();
    if (nextDouble > 0.8) {
      throw Exception('$nextDouble');
      // how can I keep generating next random numbers?
    }
    yield nextDouble;
  }
}
```

The above code shows the intent of `sum20RandomNumbers()` is to sum exactly 20 random numbers up, but it will be stopped after an Exception being thrown in generator function `generateRandomNumbers()`. How to keep generator function yielding values after throwing an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that for `sync*` functions.

The only way an `Iterable` can report an error is by making the `Iterator`'s `moveNext` method throw. To do that, a `sync*` method must throw.
When a `sync*` function throws, it terminates the body of the function, which makes it impossible for that body to continue and produce more values.

The same thing happens for `async*` functions which throw, but there you also have a different way to emit an error. Because a stream can report errors as part of the stream, it is possible to emit errors and continue, you just can't do it by *throwing*.

```
Stream<double> generateRandomNumbers([int seed]) async* {
  final random = Random(seed);
  while (true) {
    final nextDouble = random.nextDouble();
    if (nextDouble > 0.8) {
      yield* Future<double>.error(Exception('$nextDouble')).asStream();
      continue;
    }
    yield nextDouble;
  }
}
```

The trick is to `yield*` a stream which contains an error. You can do that in many different ways.

```
yield* Stream.error(theError);
```

This constructor was added in Dart 2.5 and is the easiest approach. Other alternatives are:

```
yield* Future<double>.error(theError).asStream();
```

or

```
yield* () async* { throw theError; } ();
```

or

```
yield* (StreamController<double>()..addError(theError)..close()).stream;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But when I use `yield* Future.error(Exception('$nextDouble')).asStream();`, Dart runtime will complain　`Ignore large number: type '_ControllerStream<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<double>'`

Comment: My bad, you need to make it a `Stream<double>`. Code updated.